# How can I handle drawing a circle, having that circle break, and begin drawing elsewhere?

Tags: geometry, processing

Working in Processing, I am trying to build my first generative patch. What I want to have happen is start drawing a circle somewhere on screen (a point following the path of a circle), but after a random amount of time, the circle breaks, the line goes in a random direction for a random amount of time, and begins drawing a new circle elsewhere.

Right now I have the circle being drawn, and I have a toggle mechanism that turns on and off after a random period of time. I can't figure out how to get it "break" from that original circle, let alone get it to start a new circle elsewhere. Would anybody have some advice on how to accomplish this? I think it might have an interesting visual effect.

```
Rotor r;
float timer = 0;
boolean freeze = false;

void setup() {
  size(1000,600);
  smooth();
  noFill();
  frameRate(60);
  background(255);

  timeLimit();
  r = new Rotor(random(width),random(height),random(40,100));
}

void draw() {
  float t = frameCount / 100.0;
  timer = timer + frameRate/1000;

  r.drawRotor(t);

  if(timer > timeLimit()){
    timer = 0;
    timeLimit();

    if(freeze == true){
      freeze = false; 
    }else{
      freeze = true;
    }

    background(255);
  }
}

float timeLimit(){
  float timeLimit = random(200); 
  return timeLimit;
}
```

Rotor Class:

```
class Rotor {

  color c;
  int thickness;
  float xPoint;
  float yPoint;
  float radius;
  float angle = 0;
  float centerX;
  float centerY;

  Rotor(float cX, float cY, float rad) {
    c = color(0);
    thickness = 1;
    centerX = cX;
    centerY = cY;
    radius = rad;
  } 

  void drawRotor(float t) {
    stroke(c);
    strokeWeight(thickness);
    angle = angle + frameRate/1000;
    xPoint = centerX + cos(angle) * radius;
    yPoint = centerY + sin(angle) * radius;
    ellipse(xPoint, yPoint,thickness,thickness);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

First to answer your question about "breaking" circle: you need to create new `rotor` instance or just change its properties like `center` and `radius`. If I got your idea right you just need one instance of `rotor` so just change this values:

```java
r.centerX = newX;
r.centerY = newY
r.radius = random(40,100) //as you have in setup
```

But how you can calculate new position? It could be random but you want to create path so you need to calculate it. And here comes the tricky part. So how to make connecting line and start new circle?

First you will need two `mode`. First will draw circle second will draw line. Simplest way to achieve that is by updating `rotor` draw method [You can pass `mode` variable as parameter of `drawRotor` function or as global variable]:

```
if(mode == 1){
  angle += frameRate/1000;
}else{
  radius += 2;
}
```

As you can see I just differ between increasing angle to draw circle and increasing radius to draw line (not in random direction but in way from center). Then we will need to calculate new position of circle's center. To do this we simple calculate how it would continue according to `angle` and substitute new `radius`so whole part will looks like this:

```
if(mode != 1){              
  float newR = random(40,100);
  float newX = r.centerX + cos(r.angle) * (r.radius - newR);
  float newY = r.centerY + sin(r.angle) * (r.radius - newR);      
  r.newPos(newX, newY);
  r.radius = newR; //we cant change it earlier because we need also old value
}
```

This will happen inside your "time handler" function only when you change mode back to drawing circle. Mode can be simple changed within handler

```
 mode *= -1; //but need to be init to 1 inside setup()
```

If you want to have path always visible just delete `background()` function but if you want some cool effect add this at the begging of `draw()`

```
noStroke();              //No stroke needed and you turn it on again in drawRotor()
fill( 255,255,255, 10 ); //This will set transparency to 10%
rect(0,0,width,height);  //You put layer after each "point" you draw
noFill();                //This will restore fill settings as you have before
```

[image]

[Here](http://pastebin.com/4yZJkM7X) I paste whole code just for demonstration and you should modify it according your own purpose. Better to code own version.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `background()`usually comes as first thing in draw. That's because the draw only renders at the end of each loop (frame). So calling bg at the beginning will clear all stuff drawn in last frame. If you need to persist the draws trough frames can either remove the call to `background()` or draw your stuff every frame. Or yet draw stuff in a PGraphics and display it.

The other thing is each time the 'Rotor' stops you should give it new random coordinates.

If you go for removing the `background()` call this will do the trick:

```
Rotor r;
float timer = 0;
boolean freeze = false;

void setup() {
  size(1000,600);
  smooth();
  noFill();
  frameRate(60);
  background(255);

  timeLimit();

  r = new Rotor(random(width),random(height),random(40,100));


}

void draw() {
  float t = frameCount / 100.0;
  timer = timer + frameRate/1000;

  r.drawRotor(t);

  if(timer > timeLimit()){
    timer = 0;
    timeLimit();


    //***** here new coordinates!!
     r = new Rotor(random(width),random(height),random(40,100));
    //*****


    if(freeze == true){
      freeze = false; 
    }else{
      freeze = true;
    }



    //***** no background()
    // background(255);
  }
}

float timeLimit(){
  float timeLimit = random(200); 
  return timeLimit;
}

class Rotor {

  color c;
  int thickness;
  float xPoint;
  float yPoint;
  float radius;
  float angle = 0;
  float centerX;
  float centerY;

  Rotor(float cX, float cY, float rad) {
    c = color(0);
    thickness = 1;
    centerX = cX;
    centerY = cY;
    radius = rad;
  } 

  void drawRotor(float t) {
    stroke(c);
    strokeWeight(thickness);
    angle = angle + frameRate/1000;
    xPoint = centerX + cos(angle) * radius;
    yPoint = centerY + sin(angle) * radius;
    ellipse(xPoint, yPoint,thickness,thickness);
  }


}
```

now, if you need to clear the screen, You can make a List (ArrayList?) and add a new Rotor to it when the previous is done. But you need to manage the Rotor to be able to display it self without animating as well. So new created Rotor would animate, and old ones would just display its arc without animating. Or make a PGraphis with no call to bg and display it in main canvas that can have a bg call...

A side note, be aware that relying in frameRate to times stuff makes it dependable on the system performance. You can do the same thing using `millis()`to avoid that. Not an issue so far, as this is very light yet, but may become an issue if the project grows further.